# How to restrict elements or controls inside a group box in .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a group box as per the image below. I am adding certain div's into it. But, whenever, i add any extra div, it flows out of the group box. Also, the div's that I am adding at run time resides inside the group box div in html. But still it floats, out. I guess I am missing something in the .css

[image]

Below is the **HTML**

```css
element.style {
    height: 103px;
}
.border-box {
    border: 1px solid #59bae2;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

{
    margin: 0px;
    /* padding: 0px; */
    outline: none;
}
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
.border-box #resultsection .multiselectContainer {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    position: static !important;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-table;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    /* padding: 0px; */
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-box" style="height: 103px;"> <ul>  <li> <b>HQ:</b> <label for="HQ" id="selectedHQ">NOORHQRIYA</label><span id="hiddenHQbusId" style="display:none">183287</span><br> <b>Branches:</b>   <div id="resultsection"><span class="multiselectContainer"><span class="indivSelectedText">STATE COMP INS FUND / SCIF - POLICY - SAN BERNARDINO, CA</span><input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183295"><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose"></a><br></span><span class="multiselectContainer"><span class="indivSelectedText">ARTISAN</span><input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183358"><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose"></a><br></span><span class="multiselectContainer"><span class="indivSelectedText">MCNEAL HOSPITAL OCCUPATIONAL</span><input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183360"><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose"></a><br></span><span class="multiselectContainer"><span class="indivSelectedText">CONOCO PHILLIPS</span><input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183363"><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose"></a><br></span><span class="multiselectContainer"><span class="indivSelectedText">JACKSON PURCAHSE MEDICAL CTR</span><input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183364"><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose"></a><br></span><span class="multiselectContainer"><span class="indivSelectedText">NOMATCH_TEST</span><input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183398"><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose"></a><br></span></div><br><button id="buttonSearchClass" class="link_button">Search &amp; Associate</button><input class="forColumnid" type="hidden" id="Column_31" value="31"><br><br><input class="multipleValue" type="hidden" value="183295^^STATE COMP INS FUND / SCIF - POLICY - SAN BERNARDINO, CA@@183358^^ARTISAN@@183360^^MCNEAL HOSPITAL OCCUPATIONAL@@183363^^CONOCO PHILLIPS@@183364^^JACKSON PURCAHSE MEDICAL CTR@@183398^^NOMATCH_TEST"> </li> </ul> </div>
```

I am not getting it as I have the information under the **.border-box** div, but still the information flows out of it.

Comment: the container height should be auto; which is fixed(103px) in your case.

Comment: If you want to fix your div's height,you can add a style in class .border-box{overflow: scroll;} so that content inside this div will be scrollable in both direction(i.e. x,y).

Comment: depending on your idea behind height: 103px; for the .border-box, you can do one of the following things: 1) change height to min-height, that way its atleast 103px high. 2) add overflow:auto; that way you get a scrollbar when there is to much content. 3) change the height value to auto, that way the border-box will scale with the content

Comment: I don't want to add a scroll to it.

Comment: then you need to expand the box or go through alot of trouble to shrink the contents when the content gets to big